# SQL Server 2016 , SSMS 18.3 Compatibility and Database diagram

Tags: sql-server

I've installed `SQL Server 2016 SP2` with `SSMS 18.4` (in windows server 2016 standard)

SSMS work fine (i can create database, users , linked server , database diagram ..) but the issues when i reopen my database diagram , ssms crash and restart itself

in Windows event viwer , this is the error :

```
Nom de l’application défaillante Ssms.exe, version : 2017.140.17289.0, horodatage : 0x5befcf0a
Nom du module défaillant : DataDesigners.dll, version : 2017.140.17289.0, horodatage : 0x5befcf68
Code d’exception : 0xc0000005
Décalage d’erreur : 0x0001d347
ID du processus défaillant : 0x3624
Heure de début de l’application défaillante : 0x01d5f78a921fb192
Chemin d’accès de l’application défaillante : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
Chemin d’accès du module défaillant: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Tools\VDT\DataDesigners.dll
ID de rapport : ed8de36b-f28c-40fa-9335-f143035ceec3
Nom complet du package défaillant : 
ID de l’application relative au package défaillant :
```